# pyqt5 how can dynamically change the columns in qgridlayoutq

Tags: pyqt5

I am a green hand.A day has passed when I tried to solve this problem.
I have many custom widgets  than use gridlayout. like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JEhdd.png)

when I change the window size I want the widget will move to next line or move to top line .

this is my code

```
    myLayout =QGridLayout()
    myLayout.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
    myLayout.setSpacing(0)
    myLayout.setAlignment(Qt.AlignTop| Qt.AlignLeft)
    self.setLayout(myLayout)
    t =CustomItemWidget()
    k =CustomItemWidget()
    k1 =CustomItemWidget()
    k2 =CustomItemWidget()
    k3 =CustomItemWidget()
    myLayout.addWidget(k,0,0)

    myLayout.addWidget(k1,0,1)
    myLayout.addWidget(k2,0,2)
    myLayout.addWidget(k3)
    myLayout.addWidget(t)

    self.setGeometry(300,200,550,550)
    self.setWindowTitle('Test')
    self.show()
```

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean by "will move to next line or move to top line". Can you clarify? Also, provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your code, including the custom widget.

Comment: None of the standard layouts in Qt will automatically redistribute the widgets when the window is resized. If you want to do this you need to subclass `QLayout`. [Here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-layouts-flowlayout-example.html) is an example how to implement a layout that will reflow the widgets. It's written in C++ but it shouldn't be too difficult to translate to python.